# Sum for amounts of accounts by linq in mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

**I want to return Sum for all my accounts in a list of

*Account Name | Account Type |   accountBalance*

accountBalance is sum of ( e.amount )**

[image: database, tables]

[image: in Controller , ActionResult]

Comment: Have you tried LINQ `Sum()`?

Comment: _accountBalance = e.Sum(x => x.Amount);_

Comment: Please move the code from the image into a code tag

Comment: Show your code, not images of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add group by in your query and then you can use Sum, so you need to do something like

```
group e by new 
{
fa.accountName,
fa.accountType
} into gp
select new AccountsSummary
{
accountName = gp.Key.accountName, 
accountType = gp.Key.accountType,
accountBalance = gp.Sum(u=>u.amount) 
}
```

Comment: @GeorgeIdeas Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, you're looking for LINQ `Sum`:

```
accountBalance = e.Sum(x => x.Amount);
```

Comment: does not accept:    (Error)  'AccountingEntries' does not contain a definition for 'Sum' and no extension method 'Sum' accepting a first argument of type 'AccountingEntries' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @GeorgeIdeas Have you referenced `System.Linq`

Comment: You cannot Sum on just a single item